# Can an infinitesimally thin conducting shell be polarized?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors, polarization

Suppose we have a infinitesimally thin conducting shell and a point charged placed at it's center. Can this shell be polarized by this point charge? That is, can charge be induced on this shell in this case?

I think not, as positive ions and free electrons are residing on surface only and they cannot be separated much as it is already infinitesimally thin.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If we have infinitesimally small elements of charge - yes.

Comment: The position of central charge is not going to affect the distribution of +/- charges on the outer surface of conducting shell, since E=0 inside conductor.

Comment: @KP99 but how does that account for no polarisation of spherical shell by electric field of point charge

Comment: Local charge distribution is inversely related to radius of curvature. Besides, the electric field lines due to point charge can't pass through the conducting material, so the outer charge distribution is unaware of the location of point charge or shape of cavity. Either way there is no possibility for polarization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping in mind that the conductor is infinitesimally thin i.e equal or just exceeding diameter of electron,  it can't be polarised. You are correct!!